# How can I load a dynamically generated XML file?

Tags: asp-classic, jscript

Assume I have a file that contains :

```
<%
    Response.write("<my_tag>value</my_tag>")
%>
```

If I get it as an ordinary XML file, I get an error telling me that the XML have not the right format because it begin by "<%". How can I read this XML dynamically generated ?

**Edit:**

In fact, it was an illusion. The Server.Execute method just print the other file. What can I do ? How could I put the result of an ASP page in a string that I could read by loadXML method ? Or how could I just process the file before loading it ?

Comment: Phil, that's not an XML file.

Comment: That's an ASP file outputting some XML-like tag. Your title suggest you want to load this file. How, by what? Load it into the ASP code on the server, or load it in a browser?

Comment: @Diodeus: Load it from another ASP file.

Comment: If you have further problems **post them in new question**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a file extension that ASP will know to process, or tell ASP to process the file extension you're using. The server has to know to process the file and give you the dynamic result. It doesn't treat every file served as a classic ASP file, you have to tell it what to treat the file as if you're using a non-standard extension for ASP. You can do this by mapping the classic ASP handler to the file type you're trying to HTTP GET.

Comment: The extension is .asp and the file is not processed by the server. Is there an ASP command to force it ?

Comment: Oups ! Forget what I sais. See below.

Answer (score 0):

Use an .asp extension and set the Content Type:

```
<%
Response.CharSet = "utf-8"
Response.Buffer = True
Response.ContentType="text/xml"

Response.Write "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"
Response.Write "<my_tag>value</my_tag>"

Response.Flush
%>
```

You might take a look here: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/

Comment: The server does not process the file anyway. This leads to an "A name was started with an invalid character." error.